# Is every odd number of the form $2p+q$?

Tags: number-theory

Is there any counterexample of the following statement?

"Every odd number( $>5$) can be written as $2p+q$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers."

Comment: It has a whiff of the Goldbach conjecture, where while no counterexample has been found, has not been proven either.

Comment: General reference: [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson%27s_conjecture). Search on that to learn more about questions of this type.

Comment: @DougM How do you know? Has a computer search been done somewhere?

Comment: @ClydeKertzer I know nothing about the OP's conjecture.  I do know a little bit about Goldbach's conjecture (i.e. any even number can be written as the sum of two primes).

Comment: Ah, I understand. I thought you said there was no counterexample to the OP's conjecture.

Comment: I am not sure whether any of the known conjectures as Goldbach's conjecture or Dixon's conjecture implies this conjecture. If so, this should be worked out in a comment before this is considered to be a duplicate.

Comment: Upto $243\ 377\ 803$, the conjecture is true : More precise , there is a prime $p\le 1483$ doing the job.

Comment: Upto $766\ 707\ 661$ , there is a prime $p\le 1609$ doing the job.

Comment: Harald Helfgott proved the weak Goldbach conjecture: if $n>3$ you can find odd primes $p$, $q$ and $r$ so that $2n+1= p+q+r$.  You conjecture is much stronger than this, as you require $p=r$ (though you do also allow the case $p=r=2$ which slightly weakens it again).

If the Goldbach conjecture is true then the weak Goldbach conjecture is a trivial consequence.   Your conjecture does not seem to follow from the Goldbach conjecture and is probably equally hard.   

As even the weak Goldbach conjecture was very hard to prove, I don't think you'll get a definitive answer for some time.

Comment: Thanks for all useful comments. @Peter, could you please tell us about the number of ways which an odd number $N$ can be written by $p$ and $q$?(Is it increasing as $N$ grows?)